# How to make background of progressbar white?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-styles, android-progressbar, android-background

I'm creating an Android Application in which I have to show progress bar at an instance when there is some UI on the screen. But when the progressbar is beiing show, I want the background of the progress bar to be white in color, **not** **transparent**.

I want it like this image:

[image: image of progressbar in the app]

I tried this code:

```
public void showProgressDialogPraneeth(String message, boolean cancelable, boolean cancelOnTouchOutside) {
        if (progressDialog == null) {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this, R.style.PraneethProgressDialog);
        }
        progressDialog.setCancelable(cancelable);
        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(cancelOnTouchOutside);
        progressDialog.setMessage(message);

        if (!progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.show();
        }
}
```

And the style `PraneethProgressDialog` as:

```
<style name="PraneethProgressDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/spinner_progess_bar_color</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

What ever I try, the background is either transparent or progressbar is going to the top. I went through a lot of answers and spent a lot of time. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Create `progress.xml` in the drawable folder
Change gradient color as you require

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:pivotX="50%" 
      android:pivotY="50%" 
      android:fromDegrees="0"
      android:toDegrees="360">

    <shape 
        android:shape="ring" 
        android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:thicknessRatio="8" 
        android:useLevel="false">

    <size 
        android:width="76dip" 
        android:height="76dip" />

    <gradient 
        android:type="sweep" 
        android:useLevel="false"
        android:startColor="#447a29" 
        android:endColor="#00ffffff"
        android:angle="0"/>

    </shape>

</rotate>
```

And you Progress bar code look like this

```xml
<ProgressBar
  android:id="@+id/ProgressBar01" 
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress"
 />
```